# Faking GPS Location in PHP Request

Tags: php, header, gps, request

I'm trying to send a PHP file_get_contents request to an API which will return different results based on the GPS location of the device sending the request.

E.g. when a mobile phone makes this request, the API will use the browser GPS coordinates to figure out a response.

Is there a way to "fake" the PHP request to transmit a dummy set of GPS coordinates to the server?

Comment: Some code might help.

Comment: As far as I am aware the only way for this to happen is for javascript to ask the *browser* for geolocation info. You're not going to be able to do this unless you're using a headless browser to actually execute the page's javascript. The app you're requesting from may also rely on, or fall back to, IP address geolocation.

Comment: The javascript would be doing an ajax call to the sever to report the location. That should be traceable.

Comment: Use CURL you can fake anything